# Можно ли изменить цвет SVG картинки с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg, html, css

Всем, привет! Возникла необходимость плавно менять цвет у изображения. Из своего опыта знаю только, что можно изменить цвет текста или блочного элемента ну или любого html элемента которому доступно свойство css^color. А может быть кто-нибудь знает, можно ли применять какие-либо функции к изображениям формата SVG? по сути это же ведь xml-файл.

Вот здесь [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/DLgER/1/) того что я хочу, но пример соответственно не для картинки, а для текста.

Заранее благодарен!

[Файл изображения для примера](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/?c=512c74985628&url=ya-disk%3A%2F%2F%2Fdisk%2Fodn.svg&name=odn.svg)

Comment: Пример-то не работает или это так и задумано?

Comment: как не работает?????

Comment: точно в мозиле не работает... :(

Comment: Ну вот так вот: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) http://www.xiper.net/examples/js-plugins/effects/color/js/jquery.color.js

Comment: ИСПРАВИЛ!!!!!

Comment: Вы хотите именно animate для картинки? А пример картинки можете предоставить?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, да хочу менять цвет, приложил ссыль на пример картинки в описание

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Кроссбраузерность зависит от способа включения. Вот пример для трёх типов включения: [http://dahlström.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html](http://dahlstr%C3%B6m.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html)

Answer (score 0):

ойй, а вам не кажется, что как-то жестковато использовать столько жс-а, чтобы только плавно поменять цвет?

посмотрите подробнее в сторону css transitions/animations, мне кажется, это именно то, что вам нужно

Comment: для интерпретатора это не жесткач, тем более библейка подключается один раз и навсегда и использовать можно для любого изображения, да и к тому же код из библейки используется не весь. На счет CSS есть другие идеи, но это уже реализация с помощью стандарта CSS 3, что не есть пока хорошо, а так конечно можно и воспользоваться вот этими примерами http://weloveiconfonts.com/

Comment: да тут даже речь не столько за вопросы производительности, сколько за количество кода, хотя вы правы по поводу css3 - может оказаться, что к нему надо будет писать кучу хаков, чтобы везде ровно завелось (хотя лично я сторонник вместо поддержки всякой странноты типа ИЕ просто выводить плашку, что надо бы браузер поставить нормальный)

Comment: а где мидори-тян? :(

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midori_(%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80)
http://s4.zerochan.net/Midori.No.Hibi.full.174255.jpg

Comment: @actionless, ммм.... ну и как о_О ?

Comment: хороший лёгенький бразуер на вебките для слабых машин, из минусов - маленькая популярность, соответственно, мало экстеншенов

на основном компе юзаю chromium (тоже, кстати, нету на картинке :) )

Comment: @actionless мне больше chrome нра... прикольно подтягивать при переустановке или на другом компе данные своей гуглевой учетки, закладки, историю, плюс учетка андроид, плюс привязка к VISA, в общем чистый хромиум хорош, но у хрома свои плюсы

Comment: @Артёмыч это и лиса умеет, точно так же как и хром :)

Answer (score 0):

Svg можно инлайнить в html - современные браузеры это поддерживают. В таком варианте с его элементами можно делать что угодно, в том числе при помощи jQuery. Правда, некоторые параметры стиля могут иметь другие имена, соответственно, надо правильно указать, что анимировать.