# Исправить работу функции .click

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Не дождавшись ответа на [свой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196760/html-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-svg-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jquery) нашел [реализацию](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=952) самостоятельно. Но возник вопрос, как исправить функцию *.click* т.е. убрать появление ссылки **ЗАКРЫТЬ** и вместо нее сразу по клику делать редирект на другую страницу.

Ну вот здесь [примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/qm54u/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переписать в "примерчике"

```
document.location.hash = arr[this.id];
```

на

```
document.location = 'http://нужный_сайт.рф';
```

Comment: нижайши поклон :)